# How do I schedule a cron job to run every weekly reminder email using php

Tags: php, cron

Please advise the way to execute corn job scheduler Godaddy or other hosting server ?any help will be appreciate.

My mail() like

```
mail('bikash@techwave.com','News letter reminder','hi dear');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create cron tab using `crontab -e` command, add a following line to your cron:

   ```
   0 0 * * 0 php your/php/script/path/email_script.php
   ```
2. Create a PHP script and include your email functions here. It's a good idea to include the complete path.

---

As for setting up a cronjob in GoDaddy. their documentation explains this quite well:

> You can quickly set up a Basic Cron Job schedule using the Cron Job Manager Feature in the Control Panel in your hosting account. You can have a maximum of 10 Cron Jobs set up at any one time.

Use the 'Weekly' option:

> Weekly - Displays the Day and Hour field. Enter the day and the time of day that you want the Cron Job to run. For example, you can set your job to run each Thursday at 7:00 a.m. by selecting "Thursday" and "07:xx."

See the documentation: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3548/working-with-cron-jobs

Comment: Thanks a lot for documentation @Amal

Answer (score 1):

try storing the message in a file message.txt.  Then, in your crontab, add a command like so:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@from.com to@to.com < /path/to/message.txt
```